Is there a way to capture the sound of specific browser tab?
I want to use Whisper to generate real-time subtitles while watching live streams, so I need the program to be able to capture the sound from the browser. However, I don't know how to do this.
I know that software like Virtual Audio Cable can capture system audio, but it doesn't seem to be able to separate the audio from different source. Since I might be watching more than one live stream at the same time, I need the program to capture the sound from a specific tab.

Virtual Audio Cable can listen for separate streams, but at application level (not Chrome tabs,that's the same app). You can try to develop a specific extension, at tab level, but I'm not sure if you can do that in realtime / near realtime
